# Parshanut on Nach

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Should the tag [parshanut-torah-comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshanut-torah-comment) be used on parshanut type questions for Nach? It says in the tag wiki 'torah' but I think we should extend its use to questions such as [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13695/759). Do other users agree? Should we start a new tag for nach questions such as [parshanut-nach-comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshanut-nach-comment)? Does one already exist and I missed it?

Comment: I have accepted WAF's undisputed answer and am proceeding to change the tag wiki accordingly, though if anyone disagrees please still leave an answer below for discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most important feature of the tag in question is the methodology or set of assumptions involved in *parshanut*. These apply to differing degrees to all of *Tana"ch* and in my opinion are more productive lumped together, despite the wider scope entailed for the term *Torah*.